# jQuery selectors to Javascript conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie to JS and joined as a Junior Web Dev couple of months. I was into non-technical industry earlier and wanted to change the career.

Anyways, I want to convert this code which I have written in jQuery but I don't know how to write that in JS.

```js
$('.onload_popup .email_form .form-item-mail input.email');
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.onload_popup .email_form .form-item-mail input.email')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method returns all elements in the document that matches a specified CSS selectors, as a static NodeList object.
Here is an working example. And blur and focus only works with input element. Also `setProperty()` method interface sets a new value for a property on a CSS style declaration object.

Here is the working example based on your https://codepen.io/naveenborn/pen/PRyBvR

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.onload_popup .email_form .form-item-mail input.email');

var popup = document.querySelector("input");

popup.addEventListener("focus",onFoucsEvent);
popup.addEventListener("blur",onBlurEvent);


function onFoucsEvent() {
  document.querySelector(".onload_popup").style.setProperty ("position", "absolute", "important");
}

function onBlurEvent() {
  document.querySelector(".onload_popup").style.setProperty ("position", "fixed");
}
```

```css
.onload_popup {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 100px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="onload_popup">
  <div class="email_form">
    <div class="form-item-mail">
      
      <input class="email">
        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: May I know why this is not working then? Here is the link where I am facing issue?  https://codepen.io/naveenborn/pen/PRyBvR

Comment: @NaveenLBhandari focus and blur event only works with input elements.

Comment: @NaveenLBhandari check above improved answer.

Comment: @NaveenLBhandari `document.querySelector(".onload_popup").style.setProperty ("position", "absolute", "important");` this is the way to set css property. You missed style property in you code..

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you recommend a book/online course for me? I am new to JS and learning on my own. I have full time job as a Junior Web Dev. Also, let me know how to be good with JS programming?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `document.getElementsByClassName`, and similar functions.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Also handy: `document.querySelector()` for selectors via queries like 'div.myclass'

Comment: Yes, I am aware of selecting using ID and class. But is there a way I can select the parent to child like jQuery way?

Comment: Yes, you probably need `document.querySelectorAll( ... query )` or `document.querySelector( ... query )`, where `query` is what you fill in the jQuery version.